# .remove() not working after jquery mobile change page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a simple jquery mobile todo app.

On my index.html page I have a listview, on each li I have a link that allows you to mark each todo item as complete. This then removes the li and inserts a new one with some extra data and different styling to sigify its been completed.

This is the function that it uses:

```
markCompleted: function(id) {
    console.log(id);

    // Passing json as any store will be able to handle it (even if we change to localStorage etc)
    this.store.markCompleted(id, function(result) {

        if(result) {
            console.log("success - db updated and marked as completed");

            //var originalRow =  $('li#' + id),
            var originalRow =  $('*[data-row-id="'+id+'"]'),
                title = originalRow.find("h2").text(),
                desc = originalRow.find("p").text();

            console.log(originalRow);

            // re build the li rather than clone as jqm generates a lot of stuff

            var newRow = '<li data-row-id="' + id + '" class="completed"><a href="view.html" data-transition="slide" class="view" data-view-id="' + id +'"><h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + desc + '</p></a><a href="#" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="mark-outstanding" data-mark-id="' + id +'">Mark as outstanding</a></li>';

            // Remove from pending
            originalRow.remove();

            // Add to completed
            $('.todo-listview').append(newRow);

            // Refresh dom
            $('.todo-listview').listview('refresh');

            console.log("id length = " + $('[id='+id+']').length);

        } else {
            alert("Error - db did not update and NOT marked as completed");
        }
    });
},
```

Now that code works fine when the app loads, however if you navigate to the add page and add a record which on success redirects you back to the index.html the `originalRow.remove()` line in the above markCompleted function no longer works. It create the new row but does not remove the original row.

Heres the add funciton which uses changePage to redirect back to index.html

```
insert: function(json) {

    // Passing json as any store will be able to handle it (even if we change to localStorage etc)
    this.store.insert(json, function(result) {

        if(result) {
            console.log("success - add returned true");
            $.mobile.changePage( "index.html", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true,
                changeHash: true,
            });

        } else {
            alert("Error on insert!");
        }

    });
},
```

The events are binded as below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mark-completed', function(event) {
        console.log("Mark completed");
        //app.markCompleted(this.id);
        app.markCompleted($(this).data('mark-id'));
    });

$(document).on('click', '.add', function(event) {
        console.log("trying to insert via the add method");
        var data = JSON.stringify($('#insert').serializeObject()); 
        app.insert(data);
    });
```

This bug is driving me crazy - can anyone point out why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What give you inside markCompleted: `console.log($('[id='+id+']').length);`  checking for duplicate IDs...

Comment: try `$.mobile.activePage.find(originalRow).remove();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Hi, turns out I did have duplicate IDs which have now been replaced with different data-attributes. However, now when I "mark as completed" it doubles the h2 and p text on the duplicated row. "Get hair cut" becomes "Get hair cutGet hair cut"...

Comment: @Omar tried, no luck. I did find that I had multiple same ID's which I've now swapped for different data-attributes. But now I'm getting duplcate text each time I mark as completed?

Comment: @A.Wolff Oddly enough when I change your search to look for duplicate data-row-id's I find 2 dispite there only being one in the DOM?

Comment: @JamesJ You have two elements with same data attribute. Cannot help you more without any test case.

Comment: @A.Wolff Found the issue - you were indeed right, JQM was creating 2 "pages" within the dom due to me using changePage(index.html) rather than changePage($("#home")). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesJ glad you fix it! :)